# Set up javascript on vscode properly

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm having trouble setting up a JavaScript project in my VSCode.

What I currently have technically "works", but it wont do proper syntax highlighting and syntax error detection. For example, the following code on a fresh file won't show any error:

```
woosh();
```

The thing is, there is *no* function called `woosh` *anywhere* (not even in other files). The error is caught only when I try to actually run this code. Does anyone know what I might have done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VSCode does not highlight JS mistakes like this, because it's not a syntax error; The code above would cause a runtime error.

Comment: Then is there a tool that captures that kind of "compile-time" errors?

Comment: @nirshahar typescript

Comment: @nirshahar javascript is evaluated at runtime and not compiled. TypeScript is compiled so you can do error checking beforehand.

Comment: just changed it to a typescript file, and it works!

Comment: @nirshahar Well, holdup. You need to compile it now to actually run it. And to run it in a browser (at least if you have multiple files), you need to "pack" it. So there is much more to learn.

Comment: Cool, I will find tutorials on it!

Answer (score 1):

Install addons like eslint, jshint. If that doesn't work then I recommend learning typescript. It's a superset of javascript with strict type checking. It helps us to catch silly bugs like these.

Comment: Sadly it didn't work. I just read about typescript, and it seems cool. I will try it out. Thanks!

Comment: just changed it to a typescript file, and it works!